# Exhibitor Zookeeper - configure SSL

Tags: apache-zookeeper, netflix-exhibitor

I have a question - is it possible to configure SSL in a similar way as described in: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ZOOKEEPER/ZooKeeper+SSL+User+Guide
but with using Netflix Exhibitor (https://github.com/Netflix/exhibitor) ?

Any suggestions are greatly apprectiated